# What is the music playing at the dance in the SG-1 episode "Chimera"?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, music-identification

In the SG-1 episode ["Chimera"](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x5tfuh2) (starting at 19:25 in the linked video), Pete takes Sam to a dance. When they arrive, the band is playing a tune which starts off sounding like a sort of melodically inverted "In the Mood". Later, the music sounds like a mash-up of "Starlight Serenade" and one or two other tunes I don't recognize.

Is the music being played actual big-band era compositions which just happen to sound like the familiar titles I mentioned? If so, what are the titles?

Or, was it either royalty-free sound-alike or specifcally composed for the episode to make you think it is "vintage" music without actually being such, in order to avoid copyright clearance issues?

Comment: if you can find a video clip that might be helpful as well

Comment: @NKCampbell https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x5tfuh2 at 19:25

Comment: @JacobC.Thanks for the link